# How do I change the user's signature in MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone

I am using a MFMailComposeViewController for my application, and everything works fine, but every message has `Sent From My iPhone` at the end of it.  How can I remove this signature line or change it to read `Sent From My iPad`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the user sign. That is set in Settings / Mail, Contacts, Calendars option, on the Signature section.

That signature depends on the current user config. I think you can't change that programatically.

Best,
Pablo